# Remainder regarding some identity regarding primes.

Tags: number-theory

How do I show the following identity:
$$\sum_{p\ is \ prime} \log (1-1/p^s)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\pi(n)-\pi(n-1))\log(1-1/n^s)$$

A hint is best.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: What is $\pi(n) - \pi(n-1)$ when $n$ is prime or composite?

Comment: When $n$ is prime it equals one, and when composite it equals zero. Thanks!